# Circle coverage

Tags: geometry

What is the largest circle that can be covered with $n$ circles of given radii?

I think this is trivial with 1 and 2 circles.  3 is probably simple, but is there a general solution?

Comment: This is unclear. Do the several circles have different radii, or do you want an answer in terms of the single radius of all the circles?

Comment: "$n$ circles of varying radius", so I can choose my $n$ circles to be any size?? Then you can cover an arbitrarily large circle with just one circle...

Comment: This is the reverse of a packing problem.  They tend to be hard because the configurations are not as regular as you might think.  Take a look at [packomania](http://www.packomania.com/) to get an idea.  The page of 13-24 circles in a circle or 13-24 circles in a square can give you an idea.

Comment: See also [here](https://www2.stetson.edu/~efriedma/circovcir/) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_covering_problem).